# Finding 5 numbers with some conditions

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let $A=\{1,2,3,...,100\}$. In how many ways $a_1\lt a_2\lt a_3\lt a_4\lt a_5, a_i \in A$ can be chosen from $A$ such that $a_p -a_i \geqslant 2$ for $(p-i)=1$

My try: From $A$ we can choise 5 distinct element by ${100 \choose 5}$ ways. If distance of two $a_i$ is exactly 1 then first element can be chosen by ${96 \choose 1}$ ways and rest 4 can be chosen by the consecutive of one another. So the way to pick 5 elements such that $a_p -a_i \geqslant 2$ for $(p-i)=1$ is ${100 \choose 5} - {96 \choose 1}$.
Please see that am I right or wrong. Also another approches are also welcome. Thank you in advance

Comment: The problem asks that you don't have any pair next to each other, so you need to subtract $\{1,4,5,9,17\}$ which your calculation does not do.  You will need to use inclusion/exclusion for cases that have more than one pair next to each other if you follow your approach.

Comment: One approach here is to consider the gaps, $g_1, \cdots, g_6$ between your numbers (including the gaps before $a_1$ and after $a_5$).  These must sum to $95$ (why?).  All of these are non-negative integers, and $g_2, g_3,g_4, g_5$ must be strictly positive.  After a little algebra, Stars and Bars can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is  a way w/o explicitly using stars and bars

> - From $100$ unnumbered balls in a row, take out (say) the first five and color them.

> - $95$ balls are left with $96$ interstices including the two ends.

> - The colored balls can be replaced in $\binom{96}5$ "good" ways

> - Their indices in each arrangement are a valid choice